# Is there a way to combine mutate with another function to add a row of the numeric column means in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, row, mean, col

Thanks so much for any help. I have read tons of answers but I can't seem to figure this out for my specific case. I'm trying to use mutate() with another function to create a new row with the means of each column, should that column contain numeric variables. So far, I've only been able to add a column, which is not what I want. I tried the following:

```
x <- y %>% 
  mutate(Total = colMeans(select_if(., is.numeric), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  head
```

This only added a **column** with the means, [instead of a row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaffZ.png)

How can I add a row called "Means" with the mean of each column? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to `summarize` and then `bind_rows` with the original data. I'll use `mtcars` with the rownames augmented.

```r
mt <- rownames_to_column(mtcars)
mt %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(across(-rowname, mean)) %>%
  mutate(rowname = "Means") %>%
  bind_rows(mt) %>%
  arrange(cyl, rowname != "Means") %>%
  print(n=99)
# # A tibble: 35 x 12
#      cyl   mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb rowname            
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              
#  1     4  26.7 105.   82.6  4.07  2.29  19.1 0.909 0.727  4.09  1.55 Means              
#  2     4  22.8 108    93    3.85  2.32  18.6 1     1      4     1    Datsun 710         
#  3     4  24.4 147.   62    3.69  3.19  20   1     0      4     2    Merc 240D          
#  4     4  22.8 141.   95    3.92  3.15  22.9 1     0      4     2    Merc 230           
#  5     4  32.4  78.7  66    4.08  2.2   19.5 1     1      4     1    Fiat 128           
#  6     4  30.4  75.7  52    4.93  1.62  18.5 1     1      4     2    Honda Civic        
#  7     4  33.9  71.1  65    4.22  1.84  19.9 1     1      4     1    Toyota Corolla     
#  8     4  21.5 120.   97    3.7   2.46  20.0 1     0      3     1    Toyota Corona      
#  9     4  27.3  79    66    4.08  1.94  18.9 1     1      4     1    Fiat X1-9          
# 10     4  26   120.   91    4.43  2.14  16.7 0     1      5     2    Porsche 914-2      
# 11     4  30.4  95.1 113    3.77  1.51  16.9 1     1      5     2    Lotus Europa       
# 12     4  21.4 121   109    4.11  2.78  18.6 1     1      4     2    Volvo 142E         
# 13     6  19.7 183.  122.   3.59  3.12  18.0 0.571 0.429  3.86  3.43 Means              
# 14     6  21   160   110    3.9   2.62  16.5 0     1      4     4    Mazda RX4          
# 15     6  21   160   110    3.9   2.88  17.0 0     1      4     4    Mazda RX4 Wag      
# 16     6  21.4 258   110    3.08  3.22  19.4 1     0      3     1    Hornet 4 Drive     
# 17     6  18.1 225   105    2.76  3.46  20.2 1     0      3     1    Valiant            
# 18     6  19.2 168.  123    3.92  3.44  18.3 1     0      4     4    Merc 280           
# 19     6  17.8 168.  123    3.92  3.44  18.9 1     0      4     4    Merc 280C          
# 20     6  19.7 145   175    3.62  2.77  15.5 0     1      5     6    Ferrari Dino       
# 21     8  15.1 353.  209.   3.23  4.00  16.8 0     0.143  3.29  3.5  Means              
# 22     8  18.7 360   175    3.15  3.44  17.0 0     0      3     2    Hornet Sportabout  
# 23     8  14.3 360   245    3.21  3.57  15.8 0     0      3     4    Duster 360         
# 24     8  16.4 276.  180    3.07  4.07  17.4 0     0      3     3    Merc 450SE         
# 25     8  17.3 276.  180    3.07  3.73  17.6 0     0      3     3    Merc 450SL         
# 26     8  15.2 276.  180    3.07  3.78  18   0     0      3     3    Merc 450SLC        
# 27     8  10.4 472   205    2.93  5.25  18.0 0     0      3     4    Cadillac Fleetwood 
# 28     8  10.4 460   215    3     5.42  17.8 0     0      3     4    Lincoln Continental
# 29     8  14.7 440   230    3.23  5.34  17.4 0     0      3     4    Chrysler Imperial  
# 30     8  15.5 318   150    2.76  3.52  16.9 0     0      3     2    Dodge Challenger   
# 31     8  15.2 304   150    3.15  3.44  17.3 0     0      3     2    AMC Javelin        
# 32     8  13.3 350   245    3.73  3.84  15.4 0     0      3     4    Camaro Z28         
# 33     8  19.2 400   175    3.08  3.84  17.0 0     0      3     2    Pontiac Firebird   
# 34     8  15.8 351   264    4.22  3.17  14.5 0     1      5     4    Ford Pantera L     
# 35     8  15   301   335    3.54  3.57  14.6 0     1      5     8    Maserati Bora
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Is there a way to do this with multiple columns, or just columns containing numeric variables?

Comment: Multiple: that's what I'm doing here. If you mean "specific", then `across(c(col1, col2, col3), mean))`. Just numeric: `across(is.numeric, mean)`. The dplyr howtos and vignettes would be a really good thing to look through if you are thinking of using `dplyr` for things like this!